# ActiveMQ Artemis service is shutting down with AMQ144002: Error pushing opened file

Tags: activemq-artemis

There are Master and Slave servers configured in Artemis Cluster. Master service got shut down with the following exceptions in service-out logs:

```
2020-12-07 10:45:40,717 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] AMQ144002: Error pushing opened file: ActiveMQIOErrorException[errorType=IO_ERROR message=AMQ149000: failed to rename file activemq-data-495656.amq.tmp to activemq-data-495656.amq]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFile.renameTo(AbstractSequentialFile.java:160) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.createFile0(JournalFilesRepository.java:633) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.createFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:574) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.takeFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:535) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.pushOpenedFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:486) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository$1.run(JournalFilesRepository.java:92) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]

2020-12-07 10:45:40,717 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=NULL, message=unable to open : ActiveMQIOErrorException[errorType=IO_ERROR message=AMQ149000: failed to rename file activemq-data-495656.amq.tmp to activemq-data-495656.amq]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFile.renameTo(AbstractSequentialFile.java:160) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.createFile0(JournalFilesRepository.java:633) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.createFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:574) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.takeFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:535) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.pushOpenedFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:486) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository$1.run(JournalFilesRepository.java:92) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
```

Comment: There are Master and Slave servers configured in Artemis Cluster.Master service got shut down with the above exceptions in service-out logs

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis will shut itself down on any IO error deemed "critical." This is because the broker is essentially worthless if it can't work with the underlying persistent store. Therefore, it's best just to shut down and fix the underlying issue than to keep trying IO operations & failing.

In this case the broker is trying to rename one of the journal files but the rename operation fails. The broker in calling [`java.io.File.renameTo(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-) which returns `false` if the rename fails for any reason. Unfortunately `renameTo` doesn't specify *why* the rename failed.

Since you're using HA all the clients should fail-over to the backup and continue operating normally. My recommendation would be to inspect the filesystem for potential issues and restart the master broker when ready.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Additional information here after analyzing further, only Master was running at that time and got shutdown with the above IO error .Slave was not started.  

But later when both Master and Slave were restarted things back to normal.Do we have any suspect here as the slave was not started at that time.Also what could be the potential file system issues that could cause this.Any information on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea why your slave wasn't started. You've provided no logs or anything to investigate. Also, as I noted in my answer the `renameTo` doesn't say *why* the rename failed, just that it did. Therefore there's no specific indication of what the underlying problem was.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion .The issue was faced in our client environment.The slave was not started by the client  which was in stopped state previously when the above issue was observed.

Here are the logs and the broker xml configs from both master and the slave nodes  https://gist.github.com/sandeepmandava-smarsh/775783913e515cdbf3c1a824a3275d92

https://gist.github.com/sandeepmandava-smarsh/feb24d2dac60f44ae7ba9fcede22660c

Comment: It seems you're asking a different question than the original here, although it's unclear to me what you actually want to know. Perhaps it would be best to create a new question about this matter with the slave. If my current answer addressed your original question please mark it as correct to help other users who may encounter this in the future. Thanks!

Comment: The initial qn and the additional info given both are related .Reiterating the scenario from our client environment so that it may help you to give the inputs as required:1.Master and slave were shutdown 2.After that only Master service was started and client missed (might have forgotten) to start the Slave service 3.Master got shutdown with the above IO error message after sometime.So we would like to know if the rename of the file failures is due to the file system issues (Or) the slave being in stopped could also cause this.If it needs additional question to be raised we will do the same.

Comment: The rename failure is almost certainly related to an issue specifically with the file system. It certainly wouldn't have anything to do with whether or not the slave was running. A master broker doesn't *need* a slave in order to run properly. That would defeat the whole purpose of high-availability. If you need anything further please ask a new question. Also, if my answer addressed your original question please mark it as correct to help other users who may run into this in the future. Thanks!